# Hamburger Menu not expanding when browser in mobile screen resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have simple a `navbar` in `bootstrap`. When I reduce the size of chrome browser navbar menus turns into Hamburger icon, when I am clicking on it, menus are not visible.

`app.component.html` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eNno</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

`package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "uiassignment",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
]
}
```

`angular.json` file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "UIAssignment": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/UIAssignment",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UIAssignment:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "UIAssignment:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UIAssignment:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
        "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "UIAssignment:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "UIAssignment:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "UIAssignment",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "01c58ec0-920b-4102-a361-7d46f52578c7"
  }
}
```

`index.html` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UIAssignment</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.module.ts` file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Project information

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.7
Node: 12.18.1
Angular: 10.0.11
```

This menus is not expanding

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It is working perfectly in my system. Can you show any error in console.?

Comment: @RayeesAC - There is no error in console. It is just not expanding..  I am using Visual Studio code. Where can I get error in css options in inspect element? I am thinking error with references like jquery.

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69ezmvbh/1/). Your code works properly. I just aligned it properly and removed duplicated css and moved the js imports to the `<head>` section. However, that's not the issue.

Comment: @Tommy - Yeah, I have seen. Don't know what is the issue with my libraries and reference. Planning to put a bounty on it :). If you have worked with VisualStudio code. Probably you try creating a project and install bootstrap there that makes a lot diff then trying to run on browsers playground

Comment: Since VisualStudio code is just an editor, it should not make any difference. Can you share your whole project (on Github or import it in Stackblitz)?

Comment: @Tommy - As there is lots of restriction on my machine looks I cant upload existing code. But I can provide you all the files and information what you required.

Comment: Just provide all information on your project (structure, language, config files, ...). We can't help you if you post a running code example

Comment: Posted an answer. Does this answer your question and the hamburger menu works as expected ?

Comment: @Tommy - Hi, I involved in some other work as soon as I check, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your project. I will go step by step and explain, what is wrong.

1. You added `bootstrap` in your `package.json` and installed it using `npm i` or `yarn` (depending on what you are using). Afterwards, it is loaded inside `node_modules/bootstrap`. Additionally, requirements such as `jquery` and `popper` are installed in the folder `node_modules`. That's fine. Then, you use `angular.json` to import it. However, there are two issues:

- (a) You added it in the `"test"` section, but you have to define it in the `"build"` section
- (b) Several links are incorrect and do not exist (have a look at the `node_modules/boostrap/...` folder for instance).

Here is your "new" `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "UIAssignment": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/UIAssignment",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UIAssignment:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "UIAssignment:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UIAssignment:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "UIAssignment:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "UIAssignment:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "UIAssignment",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "01c58ec0-920b-4102-a361-7d46f52578c7"
  }
}
```

2. You add a `<!doctype html><html lang="en"> ...` inside `app.component.html`. However, `app.component.html` is loaded inside your `index.html` (using `<app-root></app-root>`), so do not add those things in there. Instead, your `app.component.html` should just contain the `<nav>...</nav>` and all other contents, but no headings / imports.
3. Since you defined Bootstrap, etc. in your `package.json` and loaded it into your project in the `angular.json`, you do not need to load it again using `<script>` or `<link>`.

Here is your "new" `app.component.html`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eNno</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and your "new" `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>UIAssignment</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Please note that you should restart your angular cli project after making edits to `angular.json`*

*Please also note that adding `bootstrap.js` and `jQuery` is not the proper way to use it inside an Angular project. Instead have a look on [`ngx-bootstrap`](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/)*

If your project does not run for any reason, you can also remove the added `styles` and `scripts` from `angular.json` and use the following lines inside `index.html` `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

using CDN links of bootstrap and call the css links two times and using different bootstrap js link of different version.

As you are using package of bootstarp .

Import it in **angular.json** as below :

```
 "styles": [
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
"scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

**Restart ng serve** if you're running it, and Bootstrap should be working on your app.